# ¿De que manera haría para que el resultado de esta consulta se viera reflejado en la respuesta de una solicitud Postman de manera correcta(json)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, hibernate

Ok, Estoy trabajando en la consulta de abajo donde su fin es encontrar todos los profesores y ver sus respectivas materias asociada y sus programas respectivo.
La base de datos es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde esta me devuelve estos resultados, que es necesario para que el frontend trabaje con ellos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que manera podría devolver el json de ese resultado que me dio esa consulta, de mi parte esa consulta la realice en spring boot de esta manera:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p.id AS id, " +
                   "CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.middle_name) AS nombres, " +
                   "CONCAT(p.first_last_name, ' ', p.second_last_name) AS apellidos, " +
                   "ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT pr) AS programas, " +
                   "ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT s) AS asignaturas, " +
                   "AVG(t.calificacion) AS calificacion " +
                   "FROM persons p " +
                   "JOIN teachers t ON t.user_id = p.id " +
                   "JOIN teacher_programs tp ON tp.teacher_id = t.id " +
                   "JOIN programs pr ON pr.id = tp.program_id " +
                   "JOIN subject_teachers st ON st.teacher_id = t.id " +
                   "JOIN subjects s ON s.id = st.subject_id " +
                   "GROUP BY p.id, nombres, apellidos", nativeQuery = true)
```

Asi es su service:

```
List<Object[]> findTeachers();
```

y la implementación:

```
@Override
    public List<Object[]> findTeachers() {
        return teacherRepository.findTeachers();
    }
```

La parte que no he podido desarrollar es el controlador y que este, retorne un responseEntity y mande el resultado que me dio la consulta en forma json como respuesta en Postman.
Alguna sugerencia para array_agg es recibida o otra forma de solucionar la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear un DTO.

```
public class PersonDto {
    private Long id;
    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    private List<String> programas;
    private List<String> asignaturas;
    private Double calificacion;
    
    // Constructor, getters y setters
    
    public PersonDto(Long id, String nombres, String apellidos, List<String> programas,
                     List<String> asignaturas, Double calificacion) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.programas = programas;
        this.asignaturas = asignaturas;
        this.calificacion = calificacion;
    }
    
    // Getters y setters
}
```

y en tu interfaz (repository) mapear los resultados al DTO.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = true)
List<PersonDto> getPersonsData();
```

Entonces en la lógica (service) consumir tu repository

```
public List<PersonDto> getPersonsData() {
        return personRepository.getPersonsData();
    }
```

Y finalmente el controller

```
@GetMapping
    public List<PersonDto> getPersons() {
        return personService.getPersonsData();
    }
```

Añado con ResponseEntity

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<PersonDto>> getPersons() {
        List<PersonDto> persons = personService.getPersonsData();
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(persons, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```